# Returning a range of references to a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have an abstract base class `T` and another class holding a vector of unique pointers to `T`. The class should support two function returning references to the entries. One of them should provide read-access, the other one should be able to modify the values in the `unique_ptr`s but not the pointers:

```
class A {
  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
  public:
    auto access() -> RefRange<T>;
    auto const_access() -> ConstRefRange<T>;
};
```

The ranges should satisfy the requirements of a `std::random_access_range`.
How can I do this without allocating additional memory in C++17 (boost is available)?

Comment: By "range" you mean container-like entities having begin&end or what exactly?

Comment: Yeah, something comparable to `std::span<T>`.

Comment: Would you be interested in something like this? https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite . Uses `std::span` if it's available, and implements it if it isn't.

Comment: I do not see how `std::span` helps to solve this problem because it does not allow `T` to be an abstract base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have boost, much of this is done by the range adaptor [`indirected`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indirected.html)

```
class A {
  private:
    static auto add_const(T & t) -> const T & { return t; }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
    using indirected = boost::adaptors::indirected;
    using transformed = boost::adaptors::transformed;
  public:
    auto access() { return data | indirected; }
    auto const_access() const { return data | indirected | transformed(add_const); }
};
```

Or with [`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) in C++20

```
class A {
  private:
    static auto indirect(const std::unique_ptr<T> & ptr) -> T & { return *ptr; }
    static auto add_const(T & t) -> const T & { return t; }
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
    using transform = std::views::transform;
  public:
    auto access() { return data | transform(indirect); }
    auto const_access() const { return data | transform(indirect) | transform(add_const); }
};
```

If you have [`<experimental/propagate_const>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const), I'd use that instead of whichever `transform(add_const)`.

```
class A {
  private:
    std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<T>>> data;
    using indirected = boost::adaptors::indirected;
  public:
    auto access() { return data | indirected; }
    auto const_access() const { return data | indirected; }
};
```

Comment: @Henk `return data | indirected;`. It could be a public typedef if you want, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @R2RT somewhere in the `decltype` it's tripping up, we don't really need the trailing return type if we just put the body there

Comment: Does the `transformed(add_const)` introduce overhead?

Comment: @Henk I would hope not, if you find it does, you could have `static auto indirect_const(const std::unique_ptr<T> & ptr) -> const T & { return *ptr; }` instead

Comment: Why can the `access` function not modify the vector?

Comment: @Henk [it can?](https://godbolt.org/z/9bbGhM3nj) Or do you mean add / remove elements?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/WjnzEj7Tv It can modify the vector. The requirement is that it only modifies the entries of the vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241621/discussion-between-caleth-and-henk).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a wrapper type which wraps the `std::vector::iterator` and provides a reference to the element contained by the `std::unique_ptr` on dereference.
Then return a simple struct containing begin and end iterators of these types.

Ex:

```
template<class T>
struct MyIterator
{
    typename std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>::iterator iter; // or const_iterator for the const version

    decltype(auto) operator*() const { return *iter->get(); }

   // implement the rest of the iterator functionality
   // ...
};

template<class T>
struct RefRange
{
    MyIterator<T> first, last;

    auto begin() const { return this->first; }
    auto end() const { return this->last; }
};

class A {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
public:
    auto access() -> RefRange<T> { return { data.begin(), data.end() }; }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `const_iterator` then only be const on the `unique_ptr`s and not on the objects itself? How would the constructor of RefRange look like?

Comment: You can force `const`ness on the object by replacing `decltype(auto)` with `const T&` for the `const` version. `RefRange` does not need a constructor. In the example i have used aggregate initialization to initialize the members. `MyIterator` probably needs constructors to be a valid `std::random_access_iterator_tag` type.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper around iterator is the first thing that comes to my mind.
It's a quick and dirty example, but you should get the idea I suppose.

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/z365js1T9

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>


template<typename T>
struct S
{
    using VecType = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
    VecType v{};

    class RefRange
    {
    public:
        RefRange(VecType& v) : r{v} {}
        struct iterator
        {
            typename VecType::iterator underlying_iterator;
            //below just return const T& for ConstRefRange
            T& operator*() const { return *underlying_iterator->get();}
            iterator& operator++(){++underlying_iterator; return *this;}
            iterator operator++(int) {iterator ret{*this}; ++(*this); return ret;}

            friend bool operator==(const iterator& l, const iterator& r)
            { 
                return l.underlying_iterator==r.underlying_iterator;
            }

            friend bool operator!=(const iterator& l, const iterator& r)
            { 
                return !(l==r);
            }
        };

        iterator begin() {return iterator{r.begin()};}
        iterator end() {return iterator{r.end()};}
    
    private:
        VecType& r;
    };

    RefRange refs() {return RefRange{v};}
};

int main()
{
    S<int> s;
    s.v.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(5)); 
    s.v.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(6)); 
    s.v.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(7)); 
    
    auto r = s.refs();
    for (auto&& el : r) {std::cout << el;}
}
```